# Wrong total entries shown in jQuery DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using jQuery DataTable js for displaying a table. To display the number of total records and current records showing, I have used the following code:

```
 $(document).ready( function() {
      $('#example').dataTable( {
        "oLanguage": {
          "sInfo": "Viewing _START_ to _END_ From _TOTAL_ " entries.
        }
      } );
    } );
```

I'm getting the wrong number of total records, but in the table I can see correct entries, and here we are not handling anything explicitly, we are just using the dataTables_info div tag in our jsp which is already mapped to sInfo.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the total entries of a datatable using the page info as follows:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();
    var info = table.page.info();

    var totalEntries = info.recordsTotal;
});
```

More information on page.info is available on the datatables website: https://datatables.net/reference/api/page.info%28%29